# Approximation of continuous function by linear combination of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, uniform-convergence, weierstrass-approximation

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b$, and let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Given $\varepsilon>0$, show that there exists $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m_1, \dots, m_n$ non-negative integers such that 
>   $$|f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_ie^{m_ix}| \leq \varepsilon, \forall x \in [a, b].$$

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761226/approximation-of-continuous-function-by-exponentials) question provided a couple of hints for a slightly different version of mine, with $m_1, \dots, m_n$ are negative integers, but I couldn't adapt them to the problem at hand or come up with any new tricks. I'm looking for a detailed solution, as I'm also on the process of learning uniform convergence and Berstein polynomials (which might be a way out of this).

Comment: Negative integers were necessary because the domain was not bounded. Here you can follow a very similar reasoning as the one you pointd out in the answer, taking into account that on your domain, the exponential are bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem,_real_version), considering the subalgebra
$$
\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ie^{m_ix} : \alpha_i\in\mathbb R,m_i\geq0\right\}
$$
of $C([a,b])$.

Comment: I understand informally that if the subalgebra above is dense in $C(X, \mathbb(R))$, $X$ a compact set, then I can approximate any continuous real-valued function defined on $X$ by a polynomial in the subalgebra, but formally why is density equivalent to uniform convergence? I ask it as a clarification of why proving the density is enough to answer my question.

Comment: Density of $\mathcal A$ in $C([a,b])$, with respect to the $\|\,\cdot\,\|_\infty$ norm, means that for every $f\in C([a,b])$ and every $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $g\in\mathcal A$ such that $\|f-g\|_\infty<\varepsilon$. This is precisely what you need to get uniform convergence. Indeed, you can find for instance $g_n\in\mathcal A$ such that $\|f-g_n\|_\infty<1/n$, hence $g_n\to f$ uniformly.

Comment: Also, *"I can approximate any continuous real-valued function defined on X by a polynomial in the subalgebra"*, there are no polynomials in the subalgebra above.

Comment: Uniform convergence is precisely the convergence induced by the norm $\|\,\cdot\,\|_\infty$. Being able to converge uniformly to any continuous function with a sequence in $\mathcal A$ is equivalent to saying that $\mathcal A$ is dense.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $\phi(y) = f(\log(y))$ on the domain $[e^a,e^b]$.

Find a polynomial $p(y) = \sum_k \alpha_k y^{m_k}$ such that $\sup_{y \in [e^a,e^b]}|\phi(y)-p(y)| < \epsilon$.

Then $\sup_{y \in [e^a,e^b]}|\phi(y)-p(y)| = \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)-p(e^x)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Is there a standard way to do it? I've attempted the Gauss function approach to a dead end.

Comment: The polynomials are dense in $C[a,b]$.