# Approximating a continuous function uniformly when f is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $f(x) \to a$ as $x\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

This question was asked in my assignment of real analysis and I am having a trouble attempting it.

> If  f is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and if $f(x)\to a$ as $x \to \infty$ then f can be uniformly approximated on $[0,\infty)$ by a function g of the form g(x)=$p(e^{-x})$ , where p is a polynomial.

Wierestrauss approximation theorem comes to mind but $[0,\infty) $ is not compact. and I am at loss of ideas on how this question should be approached. I can say that range of  f is connected but applying Weirestrauss theorem seems impossible. Also, Joining of intervals $[0,x]\cup[x,y]$... seems not correct approach as I will still not get $[0,\infty)$.

It is my humble request to you to some time on this?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(- \ln x)$ if $x>0$ and $a$ if $x=0$. Check that $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and apply Weierstrass Approximation Theorem to $g$.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2761226/42969?

Comment: @Kavi So, there exists a polynomial h(x) such that $|g(x)- h(x)|<\epsilon$. Now , putting $x= e^{-y}$, I will get required result but on [0,1].but  I want on $[0,\infty)$. So, can you please elaborate?

Comment: $|f(x)-h(e^{-x})| <\epsilon$ for all $x \geq 0$ because $e^{-x} \in [0,1]$ for all $x \geq 0$. @Avenger